# How to split on first occurrence using regex in powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

$File is a filename

(`$List = gci $path | select -expandproperty Name`, then I'll loop through each $File in $List.)

I want to take apart name1 later and manipulate it, but my code is giving me part of name2 in name1.

I'm using `-` (space dash space) as the separator for name1 and name2, however, in some cases name2 contains an extra `-` (space dash space).

Here's what I'm doing:

```
PS D:\> $File="foo - bar - bar2.ext"
[regex]$testreg = "(?<name1>.*)\s-\s(?<name2>.*)\.(?<ext>\w+$)"
$m = $testreg.Match($File)
$m.Groups["name1"].value
$m.Groups["name2"].value
$m.Groups["ext"].value

foo - bar
bar2
ext
```

I want it to give me:

```
foo
bar - bar2
ext
```

So that I can later manipulate foo and use the results to rename the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immediate fix is to use a *non-greedy* quantifier in your first capture group: follow `.*` with `?`:

```
[regex]$testreg = "(?<name1>.*?)\s-\s(?<name2>.*)\.(?<ext>\w+$)"
```

Quantifiers are *greedy* by default, so that the `.*` in `(?<name1>.*)\s-` will match up to the *last* `-` instance (preceded by a a whitespace character).

---

Another option - assuming your first capture group's target tokens have no embedded whitespace - is to let your first capture group match *non-whitespace* characters only:

```
[regex]$testreg = "(?<name1>[^\s]*)\s-\s(?<name2>.*)\.(?<ext>\w+$)"
```

Comment: Thanks.   I had tried using non-greedy on the separator, like `(\s-\s)?`, but it did not occur to me to put it in the group.

In this instance, the `name1` and `name2` include spaces, so the non-greedy quantifier is the answer.

Comment: @Xalorous: I'm glad to hear it worked. Note that `?` _by itself_  just means _optional_, which is different from non-greedy: as a non-greedy modifier, `?` modifies _other quantifiers_, namely `*` or `+`.

Comment: So, to rephrase it in my own words and test understanding: if the quantifier is "`+`" or "`*`", the "`?`" modifier tells it to stop increasing the match the first time it matches the modified group and the next group.  And without it it increases the match until it cannot add more.  Non-greedy and greedy?